# Transferring Emojis from Spreadsheet to Java

Tags: java, excel, emoji

I would like to transfer data from a google sheet (or any spreadsheet) into java.

How emoji shows up in google sheets: "That picture "

How emoji shows up in downloaded TSV: "That picture "ðŸ˜ðŸ˜ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥"

I have trouble understanding how I should be dealing with Emojis:

**Is the following correct?** I believe the way that emojis behave is that what I see in that first image is the HTML version of the emoji, and that there is an escaped version that looks something like \uD383\u2823

**How do I proceed to transfer emojis into java**:
What I want to do is be able to count the number of different emojis, so I need to separate them based on their codes.

Comment: On my machine,in your first part, I see two smileys and then three boxes with hex characters in Firefox.  It looks different in Chrome.  Why?  Because I don't have that character set installed.  That is the same problem you have with the second set - you need more character sets.  This is likely not a Java problem but either a browser or O/S issue.  How are you viewing the downloaded content?

Comment: `` is unicode `1F60D`, and `` is unicode `1F525`. Java stored text in UTF-16, so they would be 'D83D DE0D' and `D83D DD25`. Your other text is unicode `F0 178 2DC F0 178 2DC F0 178 201D A5 F0 178 201D A5 F0 178 201D A5` and I have no idea what code page that would be. But in short, you have code page conversion issue.

Comment: If I copy  directly into Eclipse, and escape with escapeJSON, I get the encoding you said, \uD83D\uDE0D. BUT when I download TSV of , the file saves ðŸ˜, which when I escape comes out to be \u00F0\u0178\u02DC\uFFFD. What is this encoding? is it transferable?

Comment: I figured out how to get the \ud83d\udd25 encoding (by copying the spreadsheet directly into the eclipse editor), but I just am confused on what the rule is....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seemed I was freaking out for no reason and should've just gone straight into Java hands first instead of thinking about encodings:

1. I downloaded my spreadsheet file into TSV
2. I parsed the TSV file using a regular BufferedReader and used

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;

```
`BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(line));
        }
    }`
```

3. output: \u00F0\u0178\u201D\u00A5\u00F0\u0178\u201D\u00A5 for input